# While installing Cloudera managaer 5

Tags: cloudera-manager

]# cat 2.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a01:c0:2:4:0:acff:fe1e:1e52: Network is unreachable"

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you create cloudera repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d/
2. Check network settings (If you are under proxy, configure proxy server details)

For more details How to install CDH, check below link

http://bigdata-tips.blogspot.in/2016/03/cdh-552-installation-on-rhelcent-os-71.html